# Как определить приложение только что запущено или восстанавливается после уничтожения?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, singleton

Собственно для чего это надо...
Во время "холодного" старта приложения с некого сайта загружаются данные (долго!!!). В приложении происходит работа с этими загруженными данными уже локально (быстро). Это было сделано для того, чтобы каждый раз не обращаться к сайту и работать уже с локальными данными.

Когда приложение уничтожается системой (при нехватке памяти и т.д.) и потом восстанавливается, то происходит опять загрузка данных с сайта (долго!!!).

Сделал восстановление через **SharedPreferences**, но в моем случае это не правильно, т.к. данные уже могут быть неактуальны.

**SharedPreferences** хранит данные пока пользователь не очистит их в настройках или не удалит приложение. Поэтому я получу данные с сайта только в первый раз, а потом буду работать только с сохраненной копией данных в **SharedPreferences**.

Кстати, в **SharedPreferences** я сохраняю также данные авторизации пользователя, которые очищать не надо, т.е. "классическое" использование **SharedPreferences**.

**Идеальный вариант работы для меня:**

1. При старте приложения *загружать* данные с сайта и восстанавливать данные авторизации пользователя.
2. При восстановлении приложения после уничтожения системой (не пользователем, а именно системой при нехватке памяти и т.д.) *восстанавливать* данные уже принятые с сайта и восстанавливать данные авторизации пользователя.

Как определить приложение только что запущено или восстанавливается после уничтожения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как определить приложение только что запущено или восстанавливается
>   после уничтожения?

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то в SharedPreferences можете хранить флаг. Если у активности сработал OnDestroy или OnStop(В зависимости от вашей задачи), то пометить 1. Если SharedPreferences хранит 1 во флаге, то значит активность уничтожалась. Таким образом в OnResume можете всегда узнать уничтожалась ли ваша активность, если нет, то снова данные не нужно загружать. А потом в OnResume не забыть поставить 0(Что активность открылась и еще не уничтожилась и не остановилась).

А вообще советую использовать сервисы и делать загрузку там. Они дают работать загрузке в фоне не тормозят работу пользователя. Плюсом пользователь не сможет их закрыть, остановить и т.п.
Ну и еще посмотрите жизненный цикл активити(Если не смотрели). Там четко описаны вызовы стандартных методов в том числе и возобновление. Возможно это то что надо.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, как раз уже делаю с помощью сервисов